# adding lists of tuples and sorting them

Tags: python, list, sum

I have the following lists of tuples:

```
mylist=[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 8)]
mylist2=[('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('c', 20), ('d', 5)]
```

Is there a way I can sum all values that share the same name and sort them in Python? Something like:

```
[('c', 28), ('b', 7), ('a', 6), ('d', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would have done it like:

```
>>> mylist=[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 8)]
>>> mylist2=[('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('c', 20), ('d', 5)]

# Step 1: Convert the list of tuples to `dict`
>>> dict_1, dict_2 = dict(mylist), dict(mylist2)

# Step 2: get set of all keys
>>> all_keys = set(dict_1.keys() + dict_2.keys())

# Step 3: Get `sum` of value for each key
>>> sum_list = [(k, dict_1.get(k, 0) + dict_2.get(k, 0)) for k in all_keys]
```

And then sort the list as:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

# Step 4: Sort in descending order based on value at index 1
>>> sorted(sum_list, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('c', 28), ('b', 7), ('a', 6), ('d', 5)]
```

*Note:* It assumes that the *key* at 0th index in tuples of both the lists are unique.

Comment: @cupcake93: Glad to help. If you feel this answer resolved your issue, mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)